# applicationDidBecomeActive getting called twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiapplicationdelegate

My app delegate method `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is getting called twice for the first time launch of the application. I have some portion of code which I want to execute only once & that I have put into `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

What should I do?

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you set a breakpoint on applicationDidBecomeActive:?  Is it exactly the same for both calls?  If not (and it shouldn't be), then that should lead you to your problem.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I got the issue. I am using Location Services. When launching for the first time after I tap on "OK" on the location services alert, my applicationDidBecomeActive gets called one more time which is the normal iOS behavior.

Comment: My app requires authentication every time it becomes active. With this location alert, the user is required to key-in password right after the alert pops up. I need to avoid that situation from happening.

Comment: @LocPham : My suggestion would be to keep an instance variable in app delegate implementation file and increment is whenever applicationDidBecomeActive is called. Do not execute your login alert code when this variable has value > 1. Do not forget to reset it. Also, this suggestion is purely based on your requirement without seeing your code. Could be a better way as well.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to call your code only once when app becomes active, try calling it from two methods.

1. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
2. `applicationWillEnterForeground`

instead of calling it only from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Answer (score 12):

This is because of location or push notification alert.

After the native location/push notification has been dismissed, `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be called.

Comment: How do we properly distinguish between a "true" applicationDidBecomeActive: when our app actually went into the background versus forcibly went into background due to location alert?

Comment: My app requires authentication every time it becomes active. With this location alert, the user is required to key-in password right after the alert pops up. I need to avoid that situation from happening.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help, but I just had the same issue with a totally simple app that doesn't use Location Services, and I found out it's an illusion. Look at the logging messages I got:

```
2012-12-22 10:47:45.329 Bizarro[10416:907] start applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-22 10:47:45.333 Bizarro[10416:907] end applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-22 10:47:45.329 Bizarro[10416:907] start applicationDidBecomeActive:
2012-12-22 10:47:45.333 Bizarro[10416:907] end applicationDidBecomeActive:
```

Look closely. Look at the *times*. The first and third messages have the same time. The second and fourth messages have the same time. They are the same messages! It's an Xcode bug; it has nothing to do with my code. Xcode is reporting the same log messages twice.

In my case, I was able to prevent this by turning off all Behaviors for Running -> Generates Output.

Answer (score 2):

With Xcode 6 there's a new reason this can happen: when you launch an app in a resizable simulator, `applicationDidBecomeActive`: will get called twice.

It launches the app with the default size class, and then applies the size you were last using—even if you were using the defaults. Any time a change in size class is applied, `applicationDidBecomeActive`: gets called.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

- Increment on `applicationDidBecomeActive`
- Decrement on callback events of permissions requests or other alerts that trigger another `applicationDidBecomeActive` when closed.

Answer (score 1):

When app launches **first** time
it calls sequentially,

1. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
2. `applicationDidBecomeActive` (**Twice**)

When we open the [Control Center](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202769) it calls only,

```
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

When app come from background to foreground it calls  sequentially

1. `applicationWillEnterForeground`
2. `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently seeing double notifications.

It's happening because my AppDelegate's init code is being called twice.
It's being called once when the `main()` does `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainMenu" owner:application topLevelObjects:&tl]` (ie, when the .XIB file is loaded), becaues the .XIB file is setting up FirstResponder to my custom AppDelegate, and then it's being called again when main() calls `[[myAppDelegate alloc] init]`.

The init code is what does the `addObserver` calls, so two observers are being set up for each notification I care about, which is why my notifications get called twice.

I'm a newbie OS X programmer, so I'm not yet sure of the best way to resolve these two, but wanted to post it here in case it's of help to others, another place to look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you possibly created an instance of your class in Interface Builder AND in your AppDelegate code, perhaps?

Comment: good check do a NSLog(@"%x",(int)self); in that delegate, make sure it is the same instance...

Comment: Even if this were the case, the application object itself can only have one delegate and would only send the message once.

Comment: @Grady: There's a format specifier for pointers: `NSLog(@"%p", self);`

Comment: Oh, you are right: i misread that. I was assuming a certain object (NOT the AppDelegate) received the message twice. I got that once with a class having identical `awakeFromNib` and `init` methods (during tests! :)). My answer is completely irrelevant to the problem, i am gonna delete it in a few seconds.

Comment: thanks Iulius Cæsar... I think there is a format specifier sized hole in my brain where that one slips through...

Comment: A `NSLog(@"%@",self)` would work, too (it defaults to `[self description]` method).

Comment: Both the times NSLog(@"%@",self) prints the same object 0xb941b0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code you want called only once when the app starts up, then use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

instead.

Otherwise, applicationDidBecomeActive will be called whenever your app becomes active again, so that doesn't just mean twice as in your case, but every time the user switches back to your app after switching to another.

Comment: Switching between applications is fine. I want code to be executed that time also. But on the first launch itself, its being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use RxSwift, then you can just throttle the application event, so it doesn't call twice in the same second:

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive)
        .throttle(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { (event) in
            self.appEnteredFromBackground()
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

private func appEnteredFromBackground() {
        Analytics.trackPageView(withScreen: .home)
        dataStore.checkIfAllowingRides()
    }
```

I put this code in my actual view controller where the logic is supposed to happen on ApplicationDidBecomeActive.

Answer (score 0):

I just check at top of `applicationDidBecomeActive:` if the request was really sent (I made a function for this, checking status), if so I return already. 
The second time in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`, the function reads the status as Deny or Allowed, because this is after the User answered the Alert.